# CakePhp: add a customized URL in $content_for_layout

Tags: php, cakephp, layout

I am working in cakephp application.

Here all the calls happening with Ajax. So user wants to keep one button or link, when user click on the link it will show one  with contains help info of that page. I'm able load div with right content. But dynamically I'm not able to display one link (Show Help) on the page dynamically.

The reason for the "Show Help" link dynamic is based on which page loads I have to pass value to JavaScript function.

Plz help me how to add this link in $content_for_layout so that it will display dynamically in all the pages.

Comment: You want to add "Show Help" link on every pages? If yes why don't you add this in your layout file?

Comment: Yea. But if I add it in layout file. It will be static. How can I set dynamic value which will call one JavaScript method. I have to pass page value in "Show Help" link.

Comment: You can create a helper for the same and call helper action in layout. Helper action will create the dynamic link.

Comment: Do let me know if you need code snippet from my side.

Comment: Oh thanks. I am new in cakephp, could you provide me code snippet? It helps to solve :)

Comment: Which version of CakePHP you are using?

Comment: I'm using cakephp 1.2.0

Comment: I have added code in the answer. Check and do let me know if you still need any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:** This is the code to create helper. Put the following code in app/views/helpers/LinkHelper.php

```
class LinkHelper extends AppHelper {
   var $helpers = array('Html');

  function showHelp() {
    $url = '';//create your url dynamically here
    $title = 'Show Help';
    return $this->Html->link($title, $url, array('class' => 'help'));
  }
```

}

**Step2:** Load the Link Helper in layout

```
$HelpLink = $this->Helpers->load('Link');
```

**Step3:** Call showHelp method of LinkHelper where Show Help link to be shown.

```
echo $HelpLink->showHelp();
```